# Keycloak running in docker and connecting to local mariaDB

Tags: docker, mariadb, keycloak

I try to setup keycloak as a docker container using a mariaDB Server which is installed on the host machine. The mariaDB Server should not run in a Docker container.

I try to run keycloak by this command:
`docker run -d --name keycloak -p 8443:8443 -v /opt/keycloak/certs:/etc/x509/https --net staticNet --ip 172.18.0.10 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD='password' -e DB_VENDOR=mariadb -e DB_ADDR=host.docker.internal -e DB_DATABASE=keycloak -e DB_USERNAME=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD='dbUserPassword' jboss/keycloak`

The Network was created with: `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 staticNet`

But keycload fails to start with error that it is not able to connect to the database host.

Is there something missing in my network Configuration? Or is something wrong with my docker run? Or do I need some special configuration for my mariaDB Server?

Comment: How is db started and how did you configure db host record?

Comment: db is started through default init.d script. What host record do you mean? It's bind address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: `host.docker.internal` - does this host name resolve to the host internal IP  in the container correctly? Do you have network connectivity to that IP? DB must be binded to that IP not to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I though you'd run mariadb as a container on the same network with `MARIADB_{env}` vars the same as keycloak's `DB_{env}`, excluding DB_ADDR, which matches that specified on the container start.